# using the webbrowser(.net) component i can't retrieve the value of the class attribute?

Tags: c#

i can't retrieve the attribute class value, it always returns an empty string, i try like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://repubblica.it");              
    
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string divClassName = "menu-panel-col";
        n = n + 1;
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;           
        HtmlElementCollection coll1= doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");               
        int counter = 0;
        int counted = coll1.Count;
        bool found = false;
        HtmlElement searchedElement = null;

        while(counter<counted || found)
        {
            HtmlElement elem=coll1[counter];
            string str = elem.GetAttribute("class");
            if(str!="")
            {
                string res = str;
            }
            if(str.Equals(divClassName))
            {
                found = true;
                searchedElement = elem;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        string msg = "";
        
    }
```

the program flow never enters the if(str!="")

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
{
    string res = str;
}
```